# K-means clustering color not changing

Tags: python, matplotlib, k-means, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook here is the kernel information

Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]

I am using k-means clustering.  When I cluster, the only color that is used is blue.  This isn't a big problem with how it is set up at the moment, but I need to scale it up so the colors need to be different. I followed a tutorial, so I don't understand all of the code 100%. The code is below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

x = [1,5,1.5,8,1,9]
y = [2,8,1.8,8,.6,11]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()

X = np.array([[1,2],[5,8],[1.5,1.8],[8,8],[1,.6],[9,11]])

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print(centroids)
print(labels)

colors = ['r','b','y','g','c','m']

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordinate:",X[i], "label:", labels[i])
    plt.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)

plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder = 10)

plt.show()

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder = 10)

plt.show()
```

I think my problem lies it this piece.

```
colors = ['r','b','y','g','c','m']

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordinate:",X[i], "label:", labels[i])
    plt.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was indeed mistaken. My previous solution was incorrect. I could finally take a decent look at the return of labels and centroids, and I think this should do what you asked.

You can give a sequence as an argument for the color= argument, so there's no need for the fol-loop

```
colors = ['r','b','y','g','c','m']
plt.scatter(x,y, color=[colors[l_] for l_ in labels], label=labels)
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], color=[c for c in colors[:len(centroids)]], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder = 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

With K means you'll want each cluster to be a different color. If you have 2 clusters, then your model `kmeans` has its labels stored in `kmeans.labels_` in an array that looks something like `[1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0...]`. To use specific colors, iterate through this before you start all your plotting code and set the colors of each point with a list:

```
colors = []
for i in kmeans.labels_:
  if i == 0:
    colors.append('blue')
  elif i == 1:
    colors.append('orange')
```

If you want to use a pre-defined Seaborn palette for your colors, you can iterate through the palette, too! For example, if you want to use the 'deep' palette:

```
palette = sns.color_palette('deep')
colors = []
for i in kmeans.labels_:
  if i == 0:
    colors.append(palette[0])
  elif i == 1:
    colors.append(palette[1])
```

If you have 3 colors, then you'd need to add another `elif` for `i == 2`, and so on.

Then when you create your plot, just set `c` argument to equal the `colors` list that you created:

```
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], c = colors)
plt.show()
```